# How to deal with warped paper after drying?

Tags: adhesives, acrylic-paint

I made a painting with acrylic paint (strong type) on paper. I think it's around 150 g/m², so it is not necessary a paper which is impossible to use for acrylic paintings. I'm using it to make quick paintings without investing too much work, but sometimes a good painting might come out which I'd like to preserve.

The paper tends to warp and roll up after drying, but as far as I can see only in one direction, so there are no bumps and humps.

Nevertheless given the case I wanted to preserve one of these trials, I think I want to fix it onto a straight surface like a cardboard or plywood. I could do it temporarily e.g. using tacks or other piercing stuff.

But I'm interested in good ways to fix it permanently to a stiff and straight substrate without piercing the artwork. Hence it boils down to glueing in some way.

**What are the best substrates and what type of glue should I use?**

I already made some thoughts of it:

Given the properties of the acrylic paint, I think the glue should not ooze through the paper too much, as it may discolor the paint, which is permeable to some degree I think. I think water based glue could work but it may be necessary to press the painting to the substrate for prolonged time.

Comment: Related: 
https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/62/how-can-i-prevent-watercolor-paper-from-buckling
https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/2393/which-glue-should-be-used-for-adhering-thin-paper
https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/17/how-can-paper-be-glued-to-cardboard-without-creating-wrinkles
https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/3846/what-kind-of-glue-to-use-for-large-area-paper-to-wood-that-is-visible-while

Comment: My bad. Hadn't searched thoroughly. I was only relying on the suggestions when typing in the subject. I'm voting to close.